# Detecting retransmitted packet with libpcap

Tags: tcp, wireshark, packet, pcap, libpcap

I'm filtering packets with libpcap with a filter like "tcp src localhost". It filters all the packets whose source is localhost (my host).
When localhost doesn't receive a TCP confirmation of an already sendt packet, localhost will forward the packet.
Not all the packets filtered by libpcap will arrive to its destination, and I need to identify when a packet is a "forwarded packet". Is there any way with libpcap to identify a forwarded packet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By my understanding, you're looking for TCP retransmissions. These can be found by **display fitters** in wireshark after capturing. These two should help you:

- Retransmitted packets can be found through the display filter `tcp.analysis.retransmission` ([more such filters](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/t/tcp.html)).
- When the receiver gets an out-of-order packet (usually indicates lost packet), it sends a ACK for the missing seq number. This is a duplicate ACK and these can be found by using `tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack` ([details](http://wiki.wireshark.org/DuplicatePackets)).

Comment: You're right. Haven't already heard about the term, but now I've seen "retransmission" is the used term by the specialists.

Comment: libpcap filter "tcp src localhost and (not tcp.analysis.retransmission)" failed compiling (pcap_compile(...)). It works on wireshark but I was looking for the libpcap filter. Thanks for your help anyway, if not possible for libpcap I will have to look for other options like tshark.

Comment: Yes thats why i said its a display filter. Its not a capture filter.