# Is it possible to not include retransmitted packets from a libpcap capture?

Tags: tcp, wireshark, libpcap, tcpdump, snort

My objective is to obtain in a unique capture the sendt tcp packets from a source host, NOT including the retransmitted packets. Is it possible to not include in the packet the retransmitted packets? 
I'm using libpcap but any help with wireshark/tshark/snort could be useful (because they use libpcap library)

Comment: check the "discussion" part here http://wiki.wireshark.org/DuplicatePackets (wireshark filter)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting forwarded packet with libpcap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813116/detecting-forwarded-packet-with-libpcap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wiresharks Documentation](http://wiki.wireshark.org/DuplicatePackets) try the following:

```
 not tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack and not tcp.analysis.retransmission
```